# What's an email server I could route a simple, non-encrypted SMTP request through manually?

Tags: python, email, smtp, telnet

I have a pretty basic networking assignment where I have to make a manual SMTP request (with the `HELO`, `MAIL FROM:`, and the like) as the client to the SMTP server in order to send an email.

It doesn't seem like you can do this anymore with Gmail, as it requires an encrypted SMTP request for obvious reasons.

I know I can do this with OpenSSL, but this is to be build with Python and it seems like an [external library](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl) would have to be used for this, which isn't allowed on the assignment.

So if possible I'd like to be able to submit this unencrypted for simplicity's sake. Are there any test servers to send non-encrypted SMTP over now a days?

Comment: You could check if your isp has a usable open smtp server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Inbox.py](https://github.com/kennethreitz/inbox.py) is here to save you (made by the author of python-requests: Kenneth Reitz), it's a very simple SMTP server "made for Humans".

Useful for your test purpose, I think.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to set this up then send it to my prof, would I? I assume it runs locally?

Comment: @DougSmith You can expose it on Internet (0.0.0.0) if you need, but as it a **very simple** server, there may be security issues. Anyway, you can run it locally on a server or something, and expose it on Internet by forwarding ports/etc... It should works.

Comment: Is there any way to be able to run it locally without pip? By just including the .py file? When I try to and use `from inbox import Inbox` it complains about no `logbook`. Which I assume is [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/logbook)? How do I get that in?

Comment: @DougSmith You can remove in the inbox.py all occurrences of logbook (which disables the logging module) or replace it by the standard logging module. There is 4 occurrences of log in the code. Should be easy.

Comment: Oh, awesome. Now that I have it running, seemingly, what do I put in the handler function from the GitHub page? I have it running now, but when I walk through the steps, setting an email as the "MAIL FROM:" and an email as the "RCPT:" it doesn't end up in the RCPT's inbox.

Comment: @DougSmith You should implement yourself the queues/containers for mail inboxes by decorating a function using `@inbox.collate` like this : `def handle(to, sender, subject, body):`, then you can put the mail into the RCPT's inbox.

Comment: Do you have any articles you could point me to on how to do that?